# How to center a value of an excel cell after merging columns in apache poi java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I am using Apache POI java to generate excel file.
I have to merge the second column a of the sheet and center the value afterwards

in my writer class I wrote the methode

```
    public void mergeColumn(final String brand,
                             final int rowStartNum,
                             final int rowEndNum,
                             final String category) {
    final XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(category);
    final XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1);
    final int firstColumn = 1;
    final XSSFCell currentBrandCell = row.createCell(firstColumn);
    currentBrandCell.setCellValue(brand);
    currentBrandCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle.getBrandStyle());

    final int lastColumn = 1;
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
        rowStartNum,
        rowEndNum,
        firstColumn,
        lastColumn
    ));

    CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(currentBrandCell, wb, CellUtil.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT, VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(currentBrandCell, wb, CellUtil.ALIGNMENT, HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

    sheet.autoSizeColumn(1, true);
    sheet.createRow(rowEndNum + 1);
}
```

and in my CustomCellStyle class I have the following

```
    brandStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    brandStyle.setFont(topHeadearFont2);
    brandStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    brandStyle.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
    putBordersThick(brandStyle);
```

and yet the value in the merged column is not centered.